# How to create a table with geometry polygons and field_ID from another table containing field_ID and lat long point in postgis

Tags: sql, postgresql, geometry, postgis, polygon

I have the following table which contains coordinates of fields from a farm. I'm trying to create polygons using points coordinates as edges of those polygons.

```
CREATE TABLE field_point (
     field_id VARCHAR(64) PRIMARY KEY,
     point_latitude DOUBLE PRECISION,
     point_longitude DOUBLE PRECISION,
     point GEOMETRY(Point,4326),
);
```

I understand that by creating geometry points using latitude and longitude of each point.

I then collect the coordinates to create a point geometry in table field_point as such:

```
UPDATE field_point SET point = ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(point_longitude, point_latitude), 4326),4326);
```

Lastly, I collect the newly created point and run convex_hull function on another table called field to return polygons as such:

```
INSERT INTO field (polygon) SELECT ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(point)) FROM field_point GROUP BY field_id;
```

I'm now not able to bring the field_id from the first table. Could you help?

Expected resuld should be the following table

```
CREATE TABLE field (
     field_id VARCHAR(64) PRIMARY KEY,
     polygon GEOMETRY(polygon,4326),
);
```

one row should the polygon created from all points defining field_id from the field_point table.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please explain clearly. Also provide your expected result

Comment: Sorry about this - I've tried to describe it better. Hope this helps

Comment: What is the `field` table in your insert query?

Comment: oh dear, sorry. I updated the output table as field - which contains the polygons

Comment: isn't it just `INSERT INTO field (field_id, polygon) field_id, SELECT ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(point)) FROM field_point GROUP BY field_id;
`

Comment: If am not wrong you want to update the value of `point` column from `field_point` table into `polygon` column in `field` table. Correct?

Comment: that is correct - I need to populate field table with the polygon as well as their id

Comment: Ok, you have `field` table already. Or you wanted to create new table

Comment: well - originally I wanted to store the polygons into field_point but this seems to not make any sense so creating a new table just to store the polygons was the way to go. so I do have this field table

Comment: Is that table created?

Comment: yes indeed - but that can be changed if needed. I'm open to alternative since I pretty much don't know what I'm doing here

Comment: Provided you the solution

Comment: ok that's what it is `INSERT INTO field (polygon) SELECT field_id, ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(point)) FROM field_point GROUP BY field_id;` learning SQL on the way - thanks for your comments

Comment: This is incorrect. See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use below query,

```
INSERT INTO field (field_id, polygon) 
SELECT field_id, ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(point)) FROM field_point;
```